# How to return intermediate response from a process or sub-process in spring boot controller when using Camunda 8

Tags: camunda

We are trying out camunda for our application and we are new to Camunda and need some help in returning intermediate response from a process/sub-process through the spring boot controller

We are designing a login flow

a. user enters the email id and clicks sign-in on the webpage

b. we are triggering an API call upon clicking sign-in and in the controller we are starting the login workflow

c. the workflow consists of 2 sub process

i) first sub-process check if the user is valid user and based on the result will return an error or generates an OTP and sends it to their mail id

d. The response from first subprocess needs to be returned to the UI so that UI can display the error message or navigate the user to next screen for user to enter the OTP they received.

e. when user enters OTP and submits another API call is invoked which will trigger the second subprocess

i) the second subprocess will verify the OTP entered and returns success or failure response based on the verification

f. the controller should be able to return the response back to UI

g. UI will display error message or navigates the user to next screen if it is successful

The problem we are facing is how to get the intermediate response coming from the sub-process 1 and return it to the UI even though the parent process will be still running until sub-process 2 is completed.

Any inputs or suggestions to address the issue is appreciated.

Thanks